# How to use a shared .clang-format inside a CLion project

Tags: c++, clion, clang-format

As typical engineering department, we have a shared .clang-format sitting at the root of our repo.

All articles I have read so far requires to create a .clang-format at the root of my project.

Ff changes are made to it, I would like my project to pickup the changes right away.

Is there a way to import that .clang-format file in CLion from it's original location?

Comment: Can you create а file reference in your project dir?

Comment: Ummm, can't put the finger on how to do this reference within the CLion IDE. :(